# Rails Heroku Gem Deployment Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku

```
config.gem: Unpacked gem authlogic-2.1.5 in vendor/gems has no specification file. Run 'rake gems:refresh_specs' to fix this.
config.gem: Unpacked gem authlogic-2.1.6 in vendor/gems has no specification file. Run 'rake gems:refresh_specs' to fix this. 
/disk1/home/slugs/283271_2d484fd_a21d/mnt/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:271:in `require_frameworks': RubyGem version error: rack(1.0.1 not ~> 1.1.0) (RuntimeError)
```

Above from Heroku Logs. Anyone know what this means? I tried google and tried to produce the .gem file and this is what my .gem file looks like this:

```
authlogic --version 2.1.6
acl9 --version ">=0.12.0" --source http://gemcutter.org
rack --version 1.0.1
```

When I run rake gems:refresh_specs I get this error :

```
littleman@littleman-laptop:~/Desktop/employee_tracker$ rake gems:refresh_specs
(in /home/littleman/Desktop/employee_tracker)
rake aborted!
undefined method `installed_source_index' for #<Gem::SourceIndex:0x00000000bba328>
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:224:in `refresh'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/tasks/gems.rake:53:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/tasks/gems.rake:53:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/tasks/gems.rake:53:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:595:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:581:in `invoke'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2041:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2013:in `top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1992:in `run'
/usr/local/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
```

This is what I get from deploying to heroku.

```
littleman@littleman-laptop:~/Desktop/employee_tracker$ git add .
littleman@littleman-laptop:~/Desktop/employee_tracker$ git commit -m "little"
[master 609c8ca] little
 9 files changed, 1026 insertions(+), 229 deletions(-)
 create mode 100755 .gems.save
littleman@littleman-laptop:~/Desktop/employee_tracker$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 26, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
Writing objects: 100% (14/14), 7.95 KiB, done.
Total 14 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Rails app detected

-----> Installing gem authlogic 2.1.6 from http://rubygems.org
       Successfully installed activesupport-3.0.0
       Successfully installed authlogic-2.1.6
       2 gems installed

-----> Installing gem acl9 >=0.12.0 from http://gemcutter.org, http://rubygems.org
       Successfully installed acl9-0.12.0
       1 gem installed

       Compiled slug size is 5.1MB
-----> Launching.... done
       http://morning-river-39.heroku.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:morning-river-39.git
   168d74d..609c8ca  master -> master
```

If you go to the [site](http://morning-river-39.heroku.com), it will say error. Then when I look at the logs, I see this.

```
config.gem: Unpacked gem authlogic-2.1.5 in vendor/gems has no specification file. Run 'rake gems:refresh_specs' to fix this.
config.gem: Unpacked gem authlogic-2.1.6 in vendor/gems has no specification file. Run 'rake gems:refresh_specs' to fix this.
/disk1/home/slugs/283271_609c8ca_a21d/mnt/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:271:in `require_frameworks': RubyGem version error: rack(1.0.1 not ~> 1.1.0) (RuntimeError)
    from /disk1/home/slugs/283271_609c8ca_a21d/mnt/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:134:in `process'
    from /disk1/home/slugs/283271_609c8ca_a21d/mnt/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    from /disk1/home/slugs/283271_609c8ca_a21d/mnt/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /disk1/home/slugs/283271_609c8ca_a21d/mnt/config/environment.rb:9
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/rails.rb:42:in `load_application'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/rails.rb:23:in `initialize'
    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:31:in `new'
    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:31
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `initialize'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `new'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `map'
    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:20
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `initialize'
    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:13:in `new'
    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:13
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `initialize'
    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1

==> dyno-2135693.log (crash) <==
config.gem: Unpacked gem authlogic-2.1.5 in vendor/gems has no specification file. Run 'rake gems:refresh_specs' to fix this.
config.gem: Unpacked gem authlogic-2.1.6 in vendor/gems has no specification file. Run 'rake gems:refresh_specs' to fix this.
/disk1/home/slugs/283271_609c8ca_a21d/mnt/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:271:in `require_frameworks': RubyGem version error: rack(1.0.1 not ~> 1.1.0) (RuntimeError)
    from /disk1/home/slugs/283271_609c8ca_a21d/mnt/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:134:in `process'
    from /disk1/home/slugs/283271_609c8ca_a21d/mnt/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    from /disk1/home/slugs/283271_609c8ca_a21d/mnt/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /disk1/home/slugs/283271_609c8ca_a21d/mnt/config/environment.rb:9
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/rails.rb:42:in `load_application'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/rails.rb:23:in `initialize'
    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:31:in `new'
    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:31
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `initialize'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `new'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `map'
    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:20
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `initialize'
    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:13:in `new'
    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:13
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `initialize'
    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1

-----> An error happened during the initialization of your app.

       This may be due to a typo, wrong number of arguments, or calling a
       function that doesn't exist.

       Make sure the app is working locally in production mode, by running it
       with RAILS_ENV (for Rails apps) or RACK_ENV (for Sinatra or other rack
       apps) set to production. e.g. RAILS_ENV=production script/server.

       Examine the backtrace above this message to debug.
```

After removing vendored/gems:

```
littleman@littleman-laptop:~/Desktop/employee_tracker$ git add -u . && git commit -am "removing vendored gems"
[master 76ec772] removing vendored gems
 2 files changed, 214 insertions(+), 255 deletions(-)
littleman@littleman-laptop:~/Desktop/employee_tracker$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 13, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 4.84 KiB, done.
Total 7 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Rails app detected
-----> WARNING: Detected Rails is not declared in either .gems or Gemfile
       Scheduling the install of Rails 2.3.8.
       See http://docs.heroku.com/gems for details on specifying gems.
       Compiled slug size is 1.1MB
-----> Launching.... done
       http://morning-river-39.heroku.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:morning-river-39.git
   ef97eef..76ec772  master -> master
littleman@littleman-laptop:~/Desktop/employee_tracker$ heroku logs

==> dyno-2135693.log (crash) <==
Missing the Rails 2.3.8 gem. Please `gem install -v=2.3.8 rails`, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.

-----> Rails can't find the expected version.

       Check to ensure you have specified the correct version of Rails in your
       Gemfile or .gems.  See http://docs.heroku.com/gems for details.

       For Rails 2.3.5 or older, you may be affected by a Rails dependency
       issue.  See http://docs.heroku.com/rails236 for details.

       Examine the backtrace above this message to debug.
```

Can anyone help? Thank you in advance, and greatly appreciated.

SOLUTION SOLVED:

After all of the above, i added the below line of code to .gems then heroku rake db:migrate 
rails --version 2.3.8 .

Thank you again for helping.

Comment: in response to your solution, don't forget to add the **pg** gem to your .gems file too, otherwise you might have problems when you come round to raking your database later on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error message mentions that your gems are packed into vendor/gems folder

```
config.gem: Unpacked gem authlogic-2.1.5 in vendor/gems has no specification file. Run 'rake gems:refresh_specs' to fix this.
```

Have you vendored them yourself prior to pushing - I don't ever recall Heroku doing that for any of my apps.

If you have vendored them yourself, are you able to **try deleting your vendor/gems folder** and then doing `git add -u .  && git commit -am "removing vendored gems"` before pushing...

Comment: Getting closer it seems. I've posted what problem I get next in the top post. Thanks again.

Comment: ahh add this to .gems `rails --version 2.3.8` on the first line and this on the second one `pg`

Answer (score 1):

One of things you'd want to change is remove the statement for "rack" version in the .gems files. Heroku will take care of it by default.

As for the authlogic did you try running refresh_specs, not sure if that would any problems anyway.

Is this a Rails 3 app ? . If yes http://docs.heroku.com/rails3  use these as instruction. You have to use the bamboo stack in heroku instead of the regular one.

Comment: I removed rack from the files and tried refresh_specs and i get this error:

Comment: run it on heroku and .. before that.. did you try pushing to heroku and see if it works without refreshing the specs

Comment: Yes, I did git push heroku master. And the push went perfectly fine.

Comment: So it works. No more deployment problem. Basically you were specifying an older version of Rack, while your version of rails depends upon >1.1.0 , so thats what was causing the problem.

Comment: But the problem is not fixed. I was initially already able to get through "git push heroku master" without any problems. It's when you try to access the site, it tells you that the application crashed. Then when I look in the logs, the above post is what I get for it's error.